# Sitecore - Event bubling

Tags: sitecore

I have two Rendering UserControls - UserControl1.ascx and UserControl2.ascx in a Layout, dynamically assigned through sitecore presentation details.

How I can call the method (GetLabelText() in UserControl1.ascx) from UserControl2.ascx using event bubbling?

This is my example code - When I click on the button (UserControl2Button1 in UserControl1.ascx) - I want to call the method GetLabelText() from UserControl2.ascx - using event bubbling.

Comment: It looks like _not good_ design. But you can try to use external storage (like Page, or Sitecore variables). Or create a custom event in UC2 - raise it on Button click. Subscribe second control to that event and make some code on event handler ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a little design problem.  You need some parent/child relationship here that is explicitly defined.  This isn't really a Sitecore problem... the proper solution will probably be obvious if you think about how you would solve this outside of Sitecore.

First, I would create a new Sublayout that explicitly references UserControl1 and UserControl2.  We'll call it ParentControl.  Then add a custom event to UserControl2.  We'll call that CustomButtonClick.  ParentControl then subscribes to that event just like it would subscribe to any control event:

```
UserControl2.CustomButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl2_CustomClick);
```

Then in the event handler:

```
void UserControl2_CustomClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1.GetLabelText();
}
```

Use ParentControl in your Presentation Details intead of Control1 and Control2 and you're done.  You've now created an explicit relationship between these controls (via ParentControl) rather than the implied relationship you were trying to achieve.  You can't have your cake and eat it too... at least, not without violating good design principles.